# Apache 2.4 https server gives connection refuse error on mac osx

Tags: apache-2.4, https, connection-refused

I'm a newbie on Apache and I was set up my https server on OS X EI follows this [article](http://brianflove.com/2014/12/02/enable-https-in-apache-on-mac-yosemite/). But I always get refuse connection error, please help.

This is my httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    #General setup for the virtual host
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kudocc/WebServer/private"
    ServerName local.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/local.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/local.example.com-access_log" common

    #SSL Engine Switch:
    SSLEngine on

    #Server Certificate:
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/local.example.com.crt"

    #Server Private Key:
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl/local.example.com.key"

    #SSL Engine Options:
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

The command `httpd -S` shows:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  local.example.com (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:293)
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Users/kudocc/WebServer/private"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

Comment: what's the output of command "httpd -t" ?

Comment: It shows `Syntax OK`. :)

Comment: you can check error log if there are any start up errors

Comment: Thanks, it shows `[Thu Mar 10 17:47:39.487005 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2514] AH02572: Failed to configure at least one certificate and key for local.example.com:443
[Thu Mar 10 17:47:39.487232 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2514] SSL Library Error: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
[Thu Mar 10 17:47:39.487236 2016] [ssl:emerg] [pid 2514] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
AH00016: Configuration Failed`, it seems that my certificate has something wrong.

Comment: Yes, It's saying your SSL certificate or private key has issues. Make sure you supply the SSL certificate in proper format. how did you generate the SSL cert?. what's complete openssl command?.

Comment: I follow this [article](http://brianflove.com/2014/12/01/self-signed-ssl-certificate-on-mac-yosemite/).

Comment: Use this command to generate the self signed SSL & replace them with existing ones.

Comment: openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt

Comment: I have tried, but fail again. `http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html`

Comment: whats the error in logs?

Comment: also try removing passphrase if you are assigning. while generating cert, leave the passphase as blank

Comment: I got the same error, I think it maybe the passphase cause it, let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I mess the config files up. So today I recover these files. Thanks to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41143/how-to-revert-default-mac-apache-install-to-original).

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
sudo cp /etc/apache2/original/extra/httpd-ssl.conf /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
sudo cp /etc/apache2/original/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Then I follow this [article](https://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-ssl) to set up my first https server successfully.

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kudocc/Sites"
    ServerName localhost
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.key"
    <Directory "/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Besides I also modify the `httpd-ssl.conf` file.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/Users/kudocc/Sites"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin you@example.com
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
TransferLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   Server Certificate:
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
#   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
#   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
#   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
#   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
#   ciphers, etc.)
#   Some ECC cipher suites (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt)
#   require an ECC certificate which can also be configured in
#   parallel.
SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server-dsa.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/server-ecc.crt"

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
#   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server-dsa.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "/private/etc/apache2/server-ecc.key"

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convenience.
#SSLCertificateChainFile "/private/etc/apache2/server-ca.crt"

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCACertificatePath "/private/etc/apache2/ssl.crt"
#SSLCACertificateFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"

#   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
#   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
#   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
#   of them (file must be PEM encoded).
#   The CRL checking mode needs to be configured explicitly
#   through SSLCARevocationCheck (defaults to "none" otherwise).
#   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCARevocationPath "/private/etc/apache2/ssl.crl"
#SSLCARevocationFile "/private/etc/apache2/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
#SSLCARevocationCheck chain

#   Client Authentication (Type):
#   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
#   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
#   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
#   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   TLS-SRP mutual authentication:
#   Enable TLS-SRP and set the path to the OpenSSL SRP verifier
#   file (containing login information for SRP user accounts). 
#   Requires OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer. See the mod_ssl FAQ for
#   detailed instructions on creating this file. Example:
#   "openssl srp -srpvfile /private/etc/apache2/passwd.srpv -add username"
#SSLSRPVerifierFile "/private/etc/apache2/passwd.srpv"

#   Access Control:
#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
#   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
#   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
#   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
#   for more details.
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#   Set various options for the SSL engine.
#   o FakeBasicAuth:
#     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
#     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
#     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
#     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
#     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context. 
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is sent or allowed to be received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly. 
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/ssl_request_log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks @serverliving.com, thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of this issue is that your Apache server is probably not set to listen on Port 443, so when the browser attempts to connect via SSL it is being refused.

The VirtualHost configuration in both your `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf` both give Apache settings on how to handle requests received via Port 443, but since Apache is not listening for requests on Port 443, it will never receive one to process.

To fix this, you must configure Apache to listen for requests on Port 443. Simply add

```
Listen 443
```

to your `httpd.conf` or `httpd-ssl.conf` file. Restart Apache and it should now work.